# Socialtables Layout Automation API returns error "Access Denied to this feature"

Tags: social-tables

I am trying to use the Layout Automation feature of the Social Tables API. When I submit my request, the following error response is returned:

```
{ "message": "Access Denied to this feature" }
```

This is the only API method that returns this message. I am able to perform other API actions successfully.

Here is the body for my request. Is something wrong with my request, or is there currently an issue with this API method?

```
{ "attendee_management": true,
"category": "Association",
"end_time": "2017-05-30T18:56:03.318Z",
"name": "Test Event",
"public": true,
"start_time": "2017-05-30T18:56:03.318Z",
"uses_metric": true,
"spaces": [
    {
        "name": "Test Space",
        "venue_id": "131935",
        "wizard": {
            "attendees": 100,
            "setup": "staggered",
            "spacing": {
                "x": 2,
                "y": 2
            }
        }
    }
],
"venue_mapper_version": 0 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request structure is correct, but access to the Layout Automation API endpoints is currently a paid feature. A good next step might be to contact sales and explore the option of adding access to your account.

Cheers,
Robert